# How to replace/remove word in a string in php

Tags: php

I've a string like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `backplanechanneldecoder20141002`  AND  WHERE  Z0 = '1'
```

I want to remove AND from it. I tried using

```
$sql_total = str_replace("AND WHERE", "WHERE", $sql_total);
$sql_total = str_replace("AND  WHERE", "WHERE", $sql_total);
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: This may be an XY problem. *Why* do you have a string like that? Fix where it comes from/is generated rather than fixing it later. It's like you ordering a red car, but as soon as you get it you paint it black because you wanted it black all along.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there's more than one space in between "AND" and "WHERE". You could deal with this using a regular expression:

```
$sql_total = preg_replace('/AND\s+WHERE/', 'WHERE', $sql_total);
```

The `\s+` part of the expression matches one or more space characters.

As mentioned in the comments, it's unclear how you have ended up with this string in the first place. It looks as though you're trying to generate a query string programmatically but haven't dealt correctly with the first/only "WHERE" clause. It would clearly be better to address the cause of this issue, rather than fixing the symptom.

Comment: #Tom Fench tried your code but it didn't worked too.

Comment: @Tom Fenech: Yes, that's better. Hopefully Umair Malik will take up your advice.